# Long rest contradiction between Official rule and Sage advice?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, rests

There are two rule clarifications posts that I am trying to wrap my head around.  But both seems to contradict each other.

Regarding an Elf that trances for 4H.... When does he gets the benefits of the long rest, after 4h or 8h ? And when is he allowed to do other things that light activity, after 4h or 8h ?

What do you make of it ?

Clarification no1 = [https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-september-2015#:~:text=Racial%20Traits&text=The%20intent%20is%20no.,at%20least%208%20hours%20long](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-september-2015#:%7E:text=Racial%20Traits&text=The%20intent%20is%20no.,at%20least%208%20hours%20long).

Clarification no.2 = https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA003

Thanks

Comment: Putting all the rules in links instead of quoting them in the question itself makes this harder than it needs to be. I've submitted an edit [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/197214/2): let me know if it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 4 hours long enough for a long rest for Elves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/is-4-hours-long-enough-for-a-long-rest-for-elves) Answers there cover that the Sage Advice quote is an update/change to earlier advice on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf

You are reading an outdated sage advice (September 2015). An Errata to the PHB changed long rests to REQUIRE sleep (which was only implied but not required before). When this errata was applied to the PHB, it caused them to reconsider the Sage Advice answer.